# current_user.is_authenticated not working on flask_login

Tags: flask, flask-login

I'm using flask_login to make the authentication and something on my login does not work. In fact the current_user attribute is always false (or anonymousUserMixin...).
I tried to change something but it didn't work. I think there are some problems with the login_user(user) part.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    except:
        return None
```

This is my login routing:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('profile', username=current_user.user_id)
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        pass_hashed = form.password.data
        if user:
            flash("user.password, pass_hashed" + user.password + "  " + pass_hashed, category="error")
            if pass_hashed == user.password:
                usr = UserData.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                session['username'] = usr.username
                next = request.args.get('next')
                # if not is_safe_url(next):
                #   return abort(400)
                # return redirect(next or url_for('index'))
                username = usr.username
                return redirect(url_for('profile', username=username))
            flash("wrong password", category="error")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        flash("invalid email", category="error")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

And this one is my user model:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.user_id)

    def get(self, id):
        return unicode(self.user_id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Email %r>' % self.email

    def check_password(self, password):
        if self.password == password:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions:
Try changing

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    except:
        return None
```

to:

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).first()
```

Despite the docs uses `.get()`, I read in some places that SQLAlchemy might have some issues due to the Unicode thing. Making this change might be enought to get it to work.

The other suggestion is to not override the `UserMixin` methods if you're not actually changing them. (Talking about the is_* methods you implemented without actually needing to)

Another thing to note is:

If you check the [`UserMixin`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/mixins.html#UserMixin) implementation for the `get_id()` method, it uses a `text_type` for converting the id. Maybe try using it as well instead of the builtin `unicode`.

If nothing works, the last solution is to change your `User` id field from `user_id` (which is kinda redundant, IMO) to `id`, cause FlaskLogin knows how to handle it as-is if that's the model identifier.